# Test for jQuery event.classList empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, operators, conditional-statements

I'm trying to test for empty on jQuery's `e.classList` (talking about the DOM map value passed by jQuery to the event if you pass the parameter for it).

So, I'm doing an absurd JS check for empty because I want to exit the function for instances where `e.classList.length` is anything less than than the integer `1`.

Oddly, I've already tried

`if ( ( typeof newTargetClasses !== "undefined" && newTargetClasses !== null ) && newTargetClasses.length > 0 ) {`

But it returns `true` even when there are no items in `e.classList` :/

```
$( window ).on( 'mouseenter', '.my-class', function( e ) {

    var newTargetClasses = e.toElement.classList;

    if ( ! isNaN( newTargetClasses.length ) && newTargetClasses.length > 0 ) {
        $.each( newTargetClasses, function() {
            if ( ! thePopover.has( '.' + this ).length > 0 ) {
                el.my_jquery_func('hide');
                return false;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

What am I missing that these booleans?  `newTargetClasses.length` during condition I'm trying to check for is returning a val of `0` and type of `number`

Comment: FYI, I voted against your edit to [@dherman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12967687/) because I felt it was such a substantial change that really you should post as an answer to your own question (and accept that), whilst *upvoting* his answer to give credit for its contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classList isn't a jQuery thing, it's a DOM API thing.  This also wouldn't work entirely cross-browser since according to MDN, IE9 doesn't support it.

[MDN ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList)

As for your code, you should be able to simplify that if condition to

```
// classList will always be falsy in IE9 so this will never run
if (e.toElement.classList && e.toElement.classList.length ) {}.
```

If you want it to be cross-browser, then you could try something like

```
if ( $.trim(e.toElement.className) ) { ... }
```